# Strange behavior from DateTime objects

Tags: c#, datetime

I do the following:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
var timeSpan = now - utc;

Console.WriteLine("Now is: " + now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:ms") + " utc is: " + utc.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:ms") + " timeSpan: " +
                    timeSpan.TotalMinutes);

Console.ReadKey();
```

It gives the following result: 
[image: Console]
And if I take the timespan.hours (which is the one I actually use) it revelas 1?
Should be 2 What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: Just a node, formatting of milliseconds isn't "...:ms", you're currently getting minutes+seconds in your millisecond output. (..:37:42:3742). Use "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff" instead.

Answer (score 6):

There is some time passes between you get times (system can even switch processes between these two calls):

```
 var now = DateTime.Now;
 // some time passes here
 var utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Thats why you have less than 2 hours between two values. You should get time only once and then *convert* it to local time:

```
 var utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
 var now = utc.ToLocalTime();
 // timeSpan: 120
```

Or use [TimeZoneInfo.ToUniversalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.touniversaltime%28VS.85%29.aspx) to convert local time to UTC time:

```
 var now = DateTime.Now;
 var utc = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToUniversalTime(now);
```

Comment: OK, but the strange thing is that the readout in the console reveals exactly 2 hours down to the millisecond? But I get your point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple: your calculation introduces an error by taking the time twice. The final result is slightly wrong, but the time taken to make the calls.

The solution is simpler.

```
  Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset.Hours);
  Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now).Hours);
```

There is no need to get or convert times when what you actually want is time zone info. The first line gets the "normal" local time offset; the second gets the offset for 'now' in case your timezone is subject to daylight saving or other adjustments.